# Loading calendar events with KnockoutJS

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, fullcalendar

I have been struggling a while now with this issue. I am unable to bind events to my fullcalendar. I am not sure what to do. I have read many articles about bindings but no success. I do not get any errors my data is not loaded. My question is do I need to create custom bindings for my events?

**ViewModel**

```
function CalendarVM() {
   this.calendarViewModel = ko.observable();
   this.viewDate = ko.observable(Date.now());


   // Observable functions
   this.LoadCalendar = function (events) {
    var self = this;
    //alert(self.calendarEvents().length);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        theme: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        editable: true,
        viewDate: self.viewDate,
        defaultView: 'month',
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            // Show modal
            $('#myModal').modal('show');

            self.SelectedDate(formatDate(start));

        },
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Admin/GetCalendarEvents',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (result) {
                    var events = [];
                    if (result != undefined && result.length > 0) {

                        result.forEach(function (entry) {
                            var sDate = formatDate(eval(entry.StartDate.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)")));
                            if (sDate != 'NaN-NaN-NaN') {
                                events.push({
                                    title: entry.Title,
                                    start: sDate,
                                    end: formatDate(eval(entry.EndDate.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"))),
                                    allDay: entry.AllDay
                                });
                            }


                        });


                        //self.calendarEvents(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS(events)));

                    }
                    console.log(events);
                    callback(events);
                }
            });
        },
        //events,
        // add event name to title attribute on mouseover
        eventMouseover: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
            if (view.name !== 'agendaDay') {
                $(jsEvent.target).attr('title', event.title);
            }
        }
    });
};

};
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // Activates Knockout
   var vm = new CalendarVM();

   ko.applyBindings(vm);
   vm.LoadCalendar();

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="calendar" data-bind="fullCalendar: calendarViewModel" class="fc fc-ltr fc-unthemed">
    </div>
```

**Code Behind**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetCalendarEvents()
{
   calendarRepo = new CalendarRepository();

   return Json(calendarRepo.GetCalendarEvents(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with knowckout so I could be wrong but the `events` function should have arguments: `function( start, end, timezone, callback )` http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ . And `callback(events)` needs to be called in `success`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that in your success function push all data to local `events` variable and you don't use it.
You should change your GetEvents method to something like this:

```
this.GetEvents = function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Admin/GetCalendarEvents',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            var events = [];
            if (result != undefined && result.length > 0) {
                result.forEach(function (entry) {
                    events.push({
                        title: entry.Title,
                        start: entry.startDate,
                        end: entry.endDate
                    });
                });

                callback(events);
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            if (err.responseText == "success") {
                self.EquiptingTracks(result);
            }
            else {
                alert(err.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Additional you should invoke that function in initialization - just pass it:

```
events: vm.GetEvents
```

Comment: How do I change "/Date(1422121540820)/" into json date? I have tried JSON.parse and $.fullCalendar.formatDate(entry.StartDate, "yyyy-MM-dd"). It all fails

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is my suggestion for this.

On this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craigcav/uKCbX/) there is an example of building a custom binding for your calendar.

What you need from that is the following:

```
ko.fullCalendar = {
    // Defines a view model class you can use to populate a calendar
    viewModel: function(configuration) {
        this.events = configuration.events;
        this.header = configuration.header;
        this.editable = configuration.editable;
        this.viewDate = configuration.viewDate || ko.observable(new Date());
    }
};

// The "fullCalendar" binding
ko.bindingHandlers.fullCalendar = {
    // This method is called to initialize the node, and will also be called again if you change what the grid is bound to
    update: function(element, viewModelAccessor) {
        var viewModel = viewModelAccessor();
        element.innerHTML = "";

        $(element).fullCalendar({
            events: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(viewModel.events),
            header: viewModel.header,
            editable: viewModel.editable
        });
        $(element).fullCalendar('gotoDate', ko.utils.unwrapObservable(viewModel.viewDate));
    }
};
```

And this is how you use it

```
<div data-bind="fullCalendar: calendarViewModel"> </div>
```

Taking your code and modifying it to the following:

```
var vm = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.calendarViewModel = ko.observable();
    self.viewDate = ko.observable(Date.now());

    self.GetEvents = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Admin/GetCalendarEvents',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                var events = [];
                if (result != undefined && result.length > 0) {
                    result.forEach(function (entry) {
                        events.push({
                            title: entry.Title,
                            start: entry.startDate,
                            end: entry.endDate
                        });
                    });
                    self.calendarViewModel(new ko.fullCalendar.viewModel({
                        events: events,
                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                        },
                        editable: true,
                        viewDate: self.viewDate
                    }));
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Code has not been tested, let me know if you run into issues then we can resolve them.

Comment: I tested your code, it does initialize the calendar but still doesn't update it or bind any data to it. The problem lies in the success method with the self.calendarViewModel observable but I don't know how to solve it. Will update my question with latest code

Comment: How do I change "/Date(1422121540820)/" into json date? I have tried JSON.parse and $.fullCalendar.formatDate(entry.StartDate, "yyyy-MM-dd"). It all fails

Comment: @G-Man You can tostring the date server side into the correct format if you wish