# FullCalendar not showing events using ko.observablearray as event souce

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, fullcalendar

I'm trying to fill my jQuery FullCalendar with a ko.observableArray

```
function calEvent(data) {
        this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
        this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
        this.start = ko.observable(data.start);
        this.end = ko.observable(data.end);
        this.color = ko.observable(data.color);
        this.allDay = ko.observable(data.allDay);
    }

 function FullEventsViewModel() {
        var self = this;           
        self.calEvents = ko.observableArray([]);

        //Get data for calendar
        $.getJSON("/JournalEntries/GetSummaryEvents?id=" + journalId, function (data) {
            var mappedcalEvents = $.map(data, function (item) { return new calEvent(item) });
            self.calEvents(mappedcalEvents);            
            });

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: self.calEvents,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            disableDragging: true,
            defaultDate: 'new Date()',
            editable: true,
            allDaySlot: false,
            slotMinutes: 5,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                window.location = "/JournalEntries/Edit/" + calEvent.id;                    
            },
            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                var myDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss TT");
                window.location = "/JournalEntries/Create?id=" + journalID + "&myDay=" + myDate;
                var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');                    
            }
        });
 };

 ko.applyBindings(new FullEventsViewModel());
```

and then the view:

```
<div id='calendar' style="width:100%"></div>
```

The call is made, it hits the server and brings back the data, which I can display if I bind to a table - works just fine - but it is not showing up in the calendar at all.

I of course have this:

```
<script src='/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

as well as the jQuery scripts and all that. The calendar renders, just no data is ever shown. Data WAS being shown when it was being done another way (MVC), but I wanted to try to do it with Knockout.

Comment: FullCalendar doesn't know how to deal with Knockout observables. There doesn't seem to be any reason for you to wrap data in observables; just populate the calendar from the raw data.
If you want your calendar to update based on changes to your array of events, you will need to make a custom binding for it. This is a nice introduction to using custom bindings: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286532/loading-calendar-events-with-knockoutjs
answer includes a custom binding.

Comment: I haven't yet tried custom binding, but I may not need an observable.. I've just been using that for everything so far so I figured it would be good for the calendar too. As it turns out, the issue I was having was more related to dates and how the calendar handles them - because I wasn't see data even without the observable. I had switched from testing in IE to testing in Chrome and for some reason I couldn't see the data in Chrome (or Firefox), but still could in IE. I messed with the dates and now I'm seeing data - something about UTC - I'm still working on it. I might try custom binding...